# How to make this working smoothly?

Tags: javascript, filter

I've found this great tutorial from w3schools and wonder if there is a way to have it in a smooth working way. Something like fadeIn maybe? I tried alot but couldn't get it working. Thanks in advance, hope anyone can help me.

Is it possible, to have the boxes fadeIn when I change to another class like from 'cars' to 'animals'?

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cow</div>
</div>
```

Need to write some text, because there is mostly code. What if I have to use that much code, to explain what I exactly mean..

Comment: you should be able to explain the effect you are trying to achieve. Literally: "I want to see Foo happen when I click Bar" "Baz should be this, when X happens and should be that when Y happens". Like think of how a client might explain what they want you to make.

Comment: Tell us what you wanna do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't know, where I can add anything on this script. Everything I tried, didn't work. Javascript etc. is very new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) from JQuery and remove the functions for removing and adding classes.

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    //w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    $(x[i]).hide();
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) { 
      //w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
      $(x[i]).fadeIn(700);      
    }
  }
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv hide cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv hide animals">Cow</div>
</div>
```